# Binary Tree level order insertion c++

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I want to insert in the tree but not using any other data structures like queue. I want to insert in level order and no matter what I code, it doesn't. Also I couldn't find any code without queues or things like that.

Here is my attempt;

```
void insert(int x) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = new node(x, NULL, NULL);
    return;
  }
  node *temp = root;
  node *prev = root;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    if (temp->left != NULL) {
      prev = temp;
      temp = temp->left;
    } else if (temp->right != NULL) {
      prev = temp;
      temp = temp->right;
    }
  }
  if (temp->left == NULL)
    prev->left = new node(x, NULL, NULL);
  else if (temp->right == NULL)
    prev->right = new node(x, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "level order"?

Comment: @dmitry Like first value should be root then it should go to left then to right then to left -> left then to left-> right then to right-> left then to right-> right...

Comment: What you want to do is basically a breadth-first-search. That can be done with a queue or alternatively (and less efficient) with a recursive function.

Comment: @n314159 bro problem is with queue I cannot understand the concept as I have to find a subtree sum equilant to a given value also that subtree should be follow bst else it should not be considered

Comment: with queue i think it is very difficult or I cannot understand how it is working

Comment: @Hasan Sorry, I don't understand what you want exactly. Also your initial post dies not talk about sums of subtrees. Please post your full problem. As for breadth-first-search with queue: You start at the root and pack all children in the queue. Then you pop the first node and add all its children to the queue. Since they are added after all siblings of this node, we will first go to the other nodes on this level an do the same. Hence, we will go through the graph level by level. Take a piece of paper and try thinking through an example including what happens in each step.

Comment: @n314159 can you provide me with the link where I can find how to insert using recursion?

Comment: @HasanKhurshid I would have to google too, so I just wrote it down below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a link for recursive insertion but it should work like this:

```cpp
bool recursion(node * current_node, node * to_insert, int &max_depth, int cur_depth) {
  if(max_depth < cur_depth) {
    max_depth = cur_depth;
  }
  for (auto & current_child : {current_node->left, current_node->right})
    if(current_child == NULL) {
      if( max_depth > cur_depth ) {
        current_child -> left = to_insert;
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      if(recursion(current_child, to_insert, max_depth, cur_depth + 1)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  return false;
}
```

This does depth-first-search (not breadth-first, I was mistaken above, they are very similar in trees) from left to right. So we will first find the left-most leaf, then the one right next to it and so on. We will always track how deep we are in the tree. If at one point we find a node on the second deepest layer that hasn't got a child, it will add the node we want to insert at this point and recurse up the tree. Due to the order in which we traverse the tree, this will find the left most open spot, so exactly what you want.

This method can return `false` if the submost layer of the tree is full. Then we have to go down to the left-most leaf and insert the node at its left child. One can also save this leaf somehow when we first find it, but that seemed more complicate to me then just searching it again (this can be done without problem in a `for`-loop).

You can replace the recursive method by an iteration with a stack (there are many sources on the internet explaining how to make a recursive depth-first-search to a iterative one).

I don't really like the in-out-parameter `max_depth` but it was the easiest to do this.